# NetBeans Java GUI Project - Design tab missing

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

I'm a total beginner in NetBeans, we have a project we need to modify with Drag&Drop, but the 'Design' tab doesnt show up for the java file in NetBeans.
[image: Can't find GUI editor]

How do I proceed?

Comment: How did you create that class? Do you have the corresponding `.form` file?

Comment: I didn't create it. I didn't find a form file in the project folder, but the GUI works fine when I start the application

Comment: Well, if there is no .form file, you can't modify it through the GUI designer. Either the window wasn't created through the GUI designer or someone deleted the file. In either case you must now make all changes manually in the Java code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The NetBeans GUI designer only works if a corresponding `.form` file is available.

If there is no such file, the "Design" tab won't be available.

Either that JFrame class wasn't created through the GUI designer or someone deleted the `.form` file. Looking at the partial code, I doubt the class was generated through the GUI designer in the first place. The GUI designer doesn't use static variables and it puts all those control creation statements at the end of the file, not the beginning.

In either case you must now make all changes manually in the Java code